# Vue-draggable-next: increase detection range for empty list

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vuedraggable

I am using [Vue-draggable-next](https://github.com/SortableJS/vue.draggable.next) along with Vue 3 to implement draggable lists. My application sometimes requires users to drag items from other lists into initially empty lists. I found that the dragging detection area is determined by how much space its elements are occupying: when there is no item in a list, it is super frustrating to drag one into the list because the detection area is soooooo small (only a dozen pixels at the start of the list on the page). This is demonstrated by the following GIF:

[image: GIF]

Is it possible to somehow set the detection range height of each list?

Comment: Can you share your code including vue-draggable?

Answer (score 1):

with this property you can expand the gap empty area:

```
:emptyInsertThreshold="50"
```

The parameter I received is positive numbers, try it, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can easily solve this problem by adding a minimum size to the draggable, `min-heigh: 200px` this is because the drop zone is not specified and needs a min-height to be set